# Is it possible to load a whole video in JavaScript in the front end that was dragged and dropped?

Tags: javascript, p5.js, tensorflow.js

I have been trying to create a web app where the user drags and drops a video file into the browser, after which some processing will be done to it with TensorFlow.js and make a prediction.

So far, I was able to:

- Load the video file and play it in an HTML video element
- Read the current frame pixel information (and even display it in a canvas element)
- I can also play and pause the video in JavaScript with p5.js

However, I want to be able to access all frames and loop through them as fast as possible (without waiting for the next frame to load in the video element).

I understand that this is often an issue easily solved by doing this in the back-end after uploading the actual video file. However, I want people to use the app knowing that their video will never be in a server somewhere.

I would happily share my code if you think it might help explain.

Comment: Depending on the video, even dedicated software may struggle to decode it at more than 30fps. In a browser, the only native way to decode a video is through the video element and that's done only in real time. You could try to load multiple video elements trying to decode the same video in parallel but I doubt you'll get great results. The other solution would be to run [ffmpeg.js](https://github.com/Kagami/ffmpeg.js/), but I guess in a browser you'll still only get near x1 decoding times... Also beware storing stills of frames will occupy considerable space in memory.